# Do aircraft have to be certified specifically for skydiving?

Tags: faa-regulations, skydiving, stc

As a skydiver, I have jumped from many different types of aircraft. Most have been specially modified for the sport. Are there requirements outside of the mechanical modifications for an aircraft to be used as a jump plane? Is there some kind of certification for jump planes in the United States?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. You use whatever old beater airplane you can get your hands on with a suitable configuration.  And you may not really need to do a mod like a jump door STC if you're willing to fly with the door removed and the plane is legal to fly that way.

When I was jumping in the late 70s it was from a Cessna 172 that was flown without a door, then later the owner installed a top hinged swing up door available as an STC kit so we wouldn't freeze on the ride up.  Other than that it's just take the seats out.

Comment: I think the 208 Caravans operate under an STC to allow 14 pax (sitting on the floor) vs max of 9 in the conventional seating arrangement.

Comment: I guess they fly with only a couple hours fuel?

Comment: If that... I've watched them:  As soon as the jumpers exit they spiral down aggressively and land well before the parachutes touch down.  Time is fuel, fuel is money!

Comment: When I was bush flying it was in a float 180, which can't be loaded to the gills like a 185, and I always flew with just enough gas for the trip, plus 30-45 min. Generally 20-25 gal. Never more than half tanks. That was the only way to haul two pax + their gear.

Comment: So is it correct to say that if I can climb out of an aircraft safely, I can jump out of it without breaking any rules for myself or the pilot?

Comment: I'm not aware of any regulation in the US or Canada that prohibits it, long as someone is in it to land it, unlike that jackass with the Taylorcraft.  That being said, it's a good idea not to go by anonymous nobodies on ASE if you are legally exposed in some way, and check the regs yourself.

Comment: @MichaelHall Parachutists are not considered passengers in determining capacity and do not require seats. They do require seatbelts even if seated on the floor. The installation of these belts can be field approved with a 337 and does not require an STC. The only constraint on the number carried is that weight and balance limits must be respected.